# MySQL merge multiple tables that share similar columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 5 tables, each with 10+ columns. They all share some similar columns but each table has columns unique to themselves. The tables are not related to each other, meaning that one record in one table won't be able to exist in another table. Therefore, when I try to concatenate them using `UNION ALL`, I get a very complicated MySQL statement since the tables have so many columns. For example, I have 2 tables:

```
Table1: ID, Name, Parts, Comments, End_Date
Table2: ID, Name, Machines, End_Date
```

If I were to combine these two tables, I would use the MySQL statement

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  Name, 
  Parts, 
  '' as Machines, 
  Comments, 
  End_Date
FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  ID, 
  Name, 
  '' as Parts, 
  Machines, 
  '' as Comments, 
  End_Date
FROM Table2
```

As you can see, the statement gets much larger the more columns and more tables there are. Is there an elegant way to concatenate these tables in a more concise statement? Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: to combine all 5 tables into a singular table, displaying all the data. The singular table would contain all columns and all records from the 5 tables

Comment: No, there is no more elegant way. The approach you are showing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For combining tables, you can use the FOREIGN KEY method from SQL that will work in MySQL. To do this, outside of the creation of your table:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD FOREIGN KEY (End_Date) REFERENCES Table2(End_Date);
```

To do this inside the creation of your table, you would just code it in after your primary key and use the bit that includes FOREIGN KEY and everything after except the ' ; '. This method will only work with one column from each table though.

For extra help that you could research if you so choose to, this website has the basic methods of all SQL languages and is extremely helpful:
[SQL Tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)